# Reference request: proof of the Rips Construction

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to understand how the Rips Construction works.

In particular, I'd like to understand why the presentation cooked up by the Rips construction (which if I'm not mistaken is not explicitly written out in Rips's 1982 paper) satisfies the small cancellation condition.

Baumslag, Miller and Short (Unsolvable Problems About Small Cancellation...) give explicit words for the presentation, and refer to Lyndon and Schupp's *Combinatorial Group Theory* for proof that it satisfies the small cancellation hypothesis. They don't give a page number (and my understanding is Lyndon Schupp was published before Rips's paper), and I'm not sure which result they refer to (possibly Theorem 10.3?).

I am aware of Arzhantseva's result (in Rips Construction Without Unique Product), which gives an explicit presentation, but I would like to understand the original construction.

Any references much appreciated :)

Comment: In Rips' construction there was no explicit presentation. He just explained how to convert any group presentation into a presentation satisfying his properties. The procedure is very explicit and exact modulo the choice of "long and complicated words" which may be basically arbitrary or even randomly chosen. The fact that the resulting presentation can satisfy small (even very small) cancelation condition was obvious for him and is still obvious for geometric group theorists now,